# Sub charts in Kibana

Tags: kibana, elasticsearch-5, kibana-5

Is it possible to create a sub chart in Kibana? For example, if a pie chart has 3 divisions and if I clicked a division, it has to go to another pie chart or other chart where it gives more details about the clicked division.